# Equivalent of [UIViewController viewDidAppear:] in cocoa (for NSView)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

Is there an equivalent to `[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]` in Cocoa?

i.e., is there a way to get a delegate callback or notification when an NSView has appeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `NSViewController` just handles nib loading. (And we didn't even have that until 10.5...) About the closest thing I know of is to override `[NSView viewDidMoveToSuperview:]` to send out appropriate messages.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case I need a callback that guarantees that the view is displayed and its initial frame is set.  viewDidMoveToSuperview: doesn't seem to be the right place for that (I haven't figured out what is).  Nevertheless, this is good to know.